# Why $B_{-1}^n(t)=B_n^{n-1}(t)=0$ where $B$ are the Berstein polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, bezier-curve

i was reading a book about Bezier curves and Berstein polynomials and i have a big doubt.

Why $B_{-1}^n(t)=B_n^{n-1}(t)=0$ where $B$ are the Berstein polynomials?

Link of the book: [http://math.aalto.fi/~ahniemi/hss2012/Notes06.pdf](http://math.aalto.fi/%7Eahniemi/hss2012/Notes06.pdf)

Pag 4, Theorem 5.

**My attempt:**

By definition of Berstein polynomial i know that:

$$B_n^{n-1}(t)=\frac{(n-1)!}{n!(n-1+n)!}\cdot t^n(1-t)^{n-1+n}$$

But if i continue then i will get:
$$\frac{(n-1)!}{n!(n-1+n)!}\cdot t^n(1-t)^{n-1+n}=\frac{1}{n(-1)!}\cdot t^n(1-t)^{-1}$$

This is wrong, because $(-1)!$ doesn't exists.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of Bernstein polynomials is
$$ B_{n,k}(t)=\binom{n}{k}t^k(1-t)^{n-k}. $$
Therefore, for $k$ outside the range $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$, the Bernstein polymomial is just zero, since the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ is defined to be zero when $k>n$ or when $k<0$. This is very typical convention.

In this case, you should not blindly apply the formula
$$ \binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} $$
because you end up with nonsense as you observed. Although, if you insist, you can interpret division by $(-1)!$ as division by "infinity" which gives you zero because the gamma function has poles at negative integers. This can be made rigorous within complex analysis.

One version of the formula that does work for arbitrary $n$ for any nonnegative integer $k$ is
$$ \binom{n}{k}=\frac{(\alpha)_k}{k!}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\dotsm(\alpha-k+1)}{k!} $$
where $(\alpha)_k$ is called the Pochhammer symbol (falling factorial). You can extend to negative $k$ by use of $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$.

Comment: I suggest you look at the definition of Bernstein polynomials that was given in the notes that the OP cited (as I did). With those definitions, the two polynomials we’re discussing are undefined nonsense. Certainly one can change the definitions (as you did), but the OP is asking about the definitions he was given, not about the ones you gave. But your remarks have some relevance, so I didn’t downvote.

Answer (score -1):

In my view, both the terms $B_{-1}^n$ and $B_n^{n-1}$ are undefined nonsense. It seems to me that your teacher is defining them to be zero just to make the summation formulas tidier. I suggest you rewrite the derivation without including the nonsense terms. The algebra might be messier, but at least it will make sense.

Or, go back in your notes to where the Bernstein polynomials are defined, and check the definitions of $B_{-1}^n$ and $B_n^{n-1}$. Maybe I’m wrong, and your teacher has defined these, but that would be unconventional. If there is a definition, it can’t be via the formula you gave, because applying that formula to $B_{-1}^n$ and $B_n^{n-1}$ includes nonsense like $(-1)!$, as you observed.